# Server for android application with image feed

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am developing an Android application for a facebook page. More specifically I want to display post images as part of a feed. The way I have achieved this thus far is by using **[restfb](http://restfb.com/)** along with **Graph API**, making requests to Graph API, receiving the images and displaying them to the feed.

My concerns are the following:

- I heavily rely on the **access token** facebook gives me for accessing those images and other page data.
- Whether, if theoretically the traffic of the application increases, can it be supported by Graph API, both performance-wise and logic-wise(extension of the access token troubles me for multiple devices).

Considering the above I have decided to go with a server-based approach. That means storing just images to the server instead of posting them on facebook. Is there an Android specific approach when building a server? Any specific documentation I should read?

**UPDATE:**
I decided to go with a Firebase Storage approach where I will upload images to the Storage and download them into my application.

Comment: I am not sure but may be what you are saying might conflict with the facebook terms & condition and privacy policy (getting data from the facebook and storing them on your server using a program / bot). I am not sure on this case but if you want to go with this approach you should check the t&c and privacy policy.

Comment: Does this apply even if the page is mine? I am not saying that the images will get downloaded from facebook to my server. Just that any new images will both go to the server and be uploaded as facebook posts as well.

Comment: if you store the images separately on your server.. then you will need some kind of link between facebook post & images stored on your server. For the post you still will be using the api.. so you have to make request for the post with the access token.

Comment: But all I need is the image not the post itself, so I can skip the api and just use a server right?

Comment: Yes... you can store images on your server and use those in your application.. for this part you don't need any kind of integration with the facebook